# Have 2 sql query into the same PHP Array

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, fetch

i got a problem about SQL Queries.

Before i used one query. :

```
$query= "SELECT hw.name as server, proc.cmd as cmd, proc.pid as pid, proc.ppid as ppid FROM hw,proc WHERE hw.id=proc.hardware_id AND hw.name LIKE :servername ORDER BY hw.name;";
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=*****;dbname=*****","*****","*****");
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($query);
$stmt->bindValue(":servername","$servername%");
$stmt->execute();
if ( $stmt->execute() != TRUE ) {
        print "Erreur requete SQL";
        print_r($stmt->errorInfo());
}
$results=$stmt->fetchAll();
```

Now i need to use 2 distinct queries, and placing them into the same array :

```
$results=$stmt->fetchAll();
```

So i had the idea to make 2 query, and place them into the same $result directly like this.

```
$query= "SELECT hw.name as server, proc.cmd as cmd, proc.pid as pid, proc.ppid as ppid FROM hw,proc WHERE hw.id=proc.hardware_id AND hw.name LIKE :servername ORDER BY hw.name;";
$query2= "SELECT hw.name as server, svc.servicename as svc, svc.displayname as svcname FROM hw,svc WHERE hw.id=svc.hardware_id AND hw.name LIKE :servername ORDER BY hw.name;";
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=*****;dbname=*****","*****","*****");
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($query,$query2);
$stmt->bindValue(":servername","$servername%");
$stmt->execute();
if ( $stmt->execute() != TRUE ) {
        print "Erreur requete SQL";
        print_r($stmt->errorInfo());
}
$results=$stmt->fetchAll();
```

For that I had modified : `$stmt = $dbh->prepare($query,$query2);`
But that is not working.

Have you any idea of how to place 2 SQL query into the same array?

Or maybe, how to create 2 array and making one with them?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't get the point of having two query, can you explain, maybe we can have the expected result with only one query

Comment: I don't get the point of having one array: the first query returns a list of processes, the second one a list of services as it seems. Both queries have different columns. So what's the use of a join: it will give the combinations of processes and services. What's the use of a UNION: it's needed to add several dummy columns. I think: two queries and two resultsets will be the best solution.

Comment: Exactly i wanted to use one array for two query because i shunk the result array in many other part.

Actually i tried to to do : 2 query, 3array (2 arrayquery and 1 result with "array_merge") but this is making too many line on my script .......

I hope you can help me because the result where perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using two SQLs you can achieve this in a single query using JOINS

```
$query= "SELECT hw.name as server, proc.cmd as cmd, proc.pid as pid, proc.ppid as ppid ,svc.servicename as svc, svc.displayname as svcname
FROM hw
INNER JOIN proc as proc ON proc.hardware_id = hw.id 
INNER JOIN svc on svc ON svc.hardware_id = hw.id

WHERE hw.name LIKE :servername AND hw.name LIKE :servername
ORDER BY hw.name";
```

Comment: I don't think this will really help, but at least this query won't fail.

Answer (score -1):

The best way to go is to combine the two queries via a `UNION` clause:

```
SELECT hw.name as server, proc.cmd as cmd, proc.pid as pid, proc.ppid as ppid 
FROM hw,proc WHERE hw.id=proc.hardware_id AND hw.name LIKE :servername
UNION
SELECT hw.name as server, svc.servicename as svc, svc.displayname as svcname 
FROM hw,svc WHERE hw.id=svc.hardware_id AND hw.name LIKE :servername
ORDER BY hw.name;
```

Comment: The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns.